# Can't get this Tic Tac Toe Game to play fair (Part2)

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

Ok after rearranging me logical approach of this tic tac toe game I was able to clean a few bugs except the biggest one.  Why is the AI rewriting the user selection.  I have tried multiple approaches to this problem however it is still over writing the users moves.  How or what should I do in order to prevent this from happening.  I have my code posted with inline comments in order to show where my problem is originating from

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame
{
private final int HEIGHT = 450;
private final int WIDTH = 500;
private static JButton [] button = new JButton[9];
private static Action [] playerTurn = new Action[9];
private Font arial = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
private static int lockButtons = 0;
private boolean game = false;
private static Random  rNum = new  Random();
private static int player = 1;



public TicTacToe ()
{
    setTitle( "TTT");
    setSize( HEIGHT, WIDTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));

    int num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
    {

        button[i] = new JButton( "B" + (i + 1));
        playerTurn[i] = new Action();
        add(button[i]);
        button[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black,10));
        button[i].setFont(arial);
        button[i].addActionListener(playerTurn[i]);
    }


    setVisible(true);
}

private class Action implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent playerMove)
    {
        //Get button pressed using GetSource Command
        JButton whatPlayer=(JButton)(playerMove.getSource()); 

                for ( int x =0; x <= button.length; x++)
                {
                    if (player == 1)
                    {
                        whatPlayer.setText("O");
                        whatPlayer.setEnabled(false);
                        validate();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Computer's Turn ");
                        player++;
                    }

                   // this block is the root and cause of my head ache

                    if( player == 2)
                    {
                        int num = rNum.nextInt(8);
                        button[num].setText("X");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"" + num ); // this is for debugging
                        button[num].setEnabled(false);
                        validate();
                        player--;

                    // This conditional statement is not being executed

                    if(button[num].equals("X") || button[num].equals("O"))
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Button is disables ");
                            return;
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }                           
    }

    public void validate()
    {
        if(button[0].getText().equals(button[1].getText()) && button[1].getText().equals(button[2].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[0].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[3].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[5].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[3].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[6].getText().equals(button[7].getText()) && button[7].getText().equals(button[8].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[6].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[0].getText().equals(button[3].getText()) && button[3].getText().equals(button[6].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[0].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[1].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[7].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[1].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[2].getText().equals(button[5].getText()) && button[5].getText().equals(button[8].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[2].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[0].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[8].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[0].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[2].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[6].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[2].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }

        int i;

        for(i=0;i<button.length;i++)
        {
            if(button[i].isEnabled())
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i == button.length)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This was a Draw");
        }
    }
    public void gameOver()
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < button.length; x++)
        {
            button[x].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    new TicTacToe();
}   
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: I understand what your are saying however I know exactly where my problem is, it is highlighted in the code I posted.  it is the conditional statement that is checking if Jbutton has been pressed already.  I am just asking for someone to see my conditional statement and comment on why it is not working properly

Comment: Yes, and you could solve that by stepping through that code with your debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "AI" consists of this line:

```
int num = rNum.nextInt(8);
```

That's just picking one of 8 (why not 9?) squares at random, with *no* checking whether or not the space is already taken.

If you really want to just pick a random space, you need to do so in a loop:

```
int num;
do {
   num = rNum.nextInt(9);
} while (!button[num].isEnabled()); // Keep going until we find a vacant space
```